# Conditional formatting color gets changed when exporting results

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an Excel tool where I click a button to process some files, and then click an "Export Results" button to move my results to a new workbook, format, and save. The Excel tool already has pre-set conditional formatting - [see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go3af.png). When I run the macro to export my results, the pink-red fill color gets changed to an orange-red. What vba code can I use to change the color back to pink-red? I have three different worksheets with varying ranges that conditional formatting needs to be applied to.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your Format screen?

Comment: Hi Frank, are you talking about the conditional formatting "manage rules" screen? I posted an image above, can you not see it?

Comment: Is the conditional formatting in the new file set using VBA?

Comment: Hi M J, it's not. The Excel tool has conditional formatting pre-set, and the conditional formatting applies to the exported results, except for the fact that the color changes.

Comment: The exported workbook maybe has a different color palette from the original one.

Comment: The only that comes to mind without more info is that the color palette might be different, and the conditional formatting is referencing the color palette, not explicit HEX/HTML or RGB colors.

Comment: Thank, both - it's set to a specific RGB model (218, 150, 148). Is there a way to make sure the conditional formatting references the explicit RGB colors?

Comment: M J and Tim, ignore my comment! I just realized that the RGB numbers I was using actually corresponded to a specific color on the palette. I just changed each number by one and the color now stays the same when exporting. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it working. Feel free to up-vote helpful comments! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color palette is different on the exported workbook, so use explicit RGB numbers (that do NOT correspond to one of the themed colors).